# Integrating C4iOS with UIKit components and storyboard

Tags: c4

Can C4iOS be used in a view? I want to use C4 in a view and integrate it with other UIKIT components. all templates and examples are using an special window and app delegate, so the c4 sketch takes all of window. Is it possible to display the sketch in a UIView as a part of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be.

In fact, all visible objects in C4 are actually views (subclasses of UIControl), so you can add them to other UIKit components using the `[object addSubview:]` method.

I haven't actually implemented using a C4Canvas in its own window or space, but since it is essentially a UIView and the C4WorkSpace is a UIViewController then it's certainly possible to do so.

---

I've built an iOS tabbed application that uses 2 C4WorkSpace objects as the primary view controllers.

https://github.com/C4Code/tabbed

This project shows that it's possible, there's a little bit of hacking to get it working. I don't have time to do a write up of the process I used to get it running right now, so I hope this is okay for the moment.

Comment: Thanks travis, Can you provide some code example or detailed guideline?

Comment: Yes I can. I am just on vacation at the moment, but can probably whip something together before the end of the weekend. If I don't, please ping me again.

Comment: Hey Abbas, just checking in to see if this helped. I have a lot more experience integrating C4 with UIKit now than when I posted this answer and code.